# Open Remote Server Local URL on my own System (Dynamic Mode)

Tags: amazon-web-services, localhost, putty, remote-server, ssh-tunnel

So I have access to a **AWS server** (let's say IP: 132.31.55.178).

I am starting a job in this server remotely which creates a local URL (http://0.0.0.0:3000/import) on the SERVER. After starting the job, I should go to this local URL, import a model there and run the main job using the UI provided in that local URL.

> Is there anyway that I can see this URL in my system and do what is
>   needed?

I did use **WinSCP** but when opening a file, it moves it to my temp folder so whatever I do there does not reflect the server in the real time.

**Any idea how to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` is not a "local" address. This address is typically used to bind a service to all IPv4 interfaces. If you are accessing something locally you are probably using the `127.0.0.1` "localhost" address.

If you have something running on an EC2 server, bound to all IPv4 interfaces, then you would access it like `<ec2-public-address>:<port>`. Given your example of address `132.31.55.178` running on port `3000` you would access this service at `http://132.31.55.178:3000/import`. Note that you would need to open port `3000` in the AWS Security Group assigned to the EC2 instance before you would be able to access that service.

Alternatively, a more secure method would be to use SSH tunneling (which you have tagged your question with, but not mentioned in your question at all). With SSH tunneling you could bind port 3000 on your local computer to port 3000 on the remote EC2 server. Then you could access the service from your local computer by loading `http://localhost:3000/import`. The SSH command to establish this tunnel would be something like:

```
ssh user@ec2-server-address -i ssh-key-location -L 3000:localhost:3000 -N
```